# ffmpeg prores 4444 banding

Tags: ffmpeg, prores

Converting an existing clean 8k Quicktime Prores 444 file in FFmpeg yields banding.  It's a lenflare with a completely smooth gradient from center out to edge of frame (no alpha).  If I use AE2020 to convert it to Prores 444, the new file is clean without banding.  Am I doing something wrong?  Here is the command string:

ffmpeg.exe -i file_8k.mov -map_metadata -1 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4 -pix_fmt yuv444p10le -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -color_range 2 -y file_6k.mov

In this case I'm converting it down to 6k, however other resolutions show the same problem, plus even converting to the same res.

Comment: Sorry didn't include my rescale code: -filter:v "scale=5760:-1" however I'm presuming this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan let me know if this qualifies as a log:  https://finalight.com/maindir/webpages/ffmpeg_batch.txt

Comment: Have you tried `-c:v prores` rather than `prores_ks` I know there were some bugs with banding a while ago with prores_ks.

Comment: Will give that a try.  Sorry, long time reply.